# Hide Toolbar on scrolling tab content

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar

I have an implementation of five tabs and a toolbar. I have used fragments for the tabs. Everything works fine except that I want to hide my toolbar whenever a tab is scrolled down and show it one it is scrolled up. Here is a graphic of my layout.[image: An illustration of the image] 
I would like help in achieving this behavior. I have tried to follow [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/) tutorial but my toolbar is still showing on scroll.
Here is my layout code for the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ollamoments_background"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/ollamoments_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include layout="@layout/ollamoments_toolbar" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:background="@color/ollamoments_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/ollamoments_upload_progress"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:max="100"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ollamoments_loading_footer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="42dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_background" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/ollamoments_splitactionbar_background"
                android:showDividers="none" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please help me achieve this behavior. Thank you.